# Как объявить std::vector::iterator it;?

Tags: итераторы, c++

```
std::vector<int, allocator>::iterator it;
```

Нужные заголовки были добавлены.

Вывод в консоль ошибок:

> ------ Построение начато: проект: tst, Конфигурация: Debug Win32 ------
>     main.cpp
>   d:\мои документы\my_code\elemmath.h(183): error C2065: allocator: необъявленный идентификатор
>   d:\мои документы\my_code\elemmath.h(183): error C2955: std::vector: для использования класса шаблон требуется список аргументов шаблон
>             c:\program files\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\vector(480): см. объявление "std::vector"
>   d:\мои документы\my_code\elemmath.h(183): error C2133: it: неизвестный размер
>   d:\мои документы\my_code\elemmath.h(183): error C2512: 
> std::_Vector_iterator>: нет подходящего конструктора по умолчанию
>   d:\мои документы\my_code\elemmath.h(185): error C2582: функция "operator =" недоступна в "std::_Vector_iterator>"
>   d:\мои документы\my_code\elemmath.h(186): error C2664: std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>
>  std::vector<_Ty>::erase(std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>,std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>): невозможно преобразовать параметр 1 из
>  "std::_Vector_iterator>" в 
>   "std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>"
>      with

Comment: я думал allocator определен где то в заголовках. без allocator все нормально. самостоятельно allocator не определял

Comment: @perfect, allocator - это правило, как Вы будете выделять память под элементы вектора. Его или надо задать, или использовать дефолтный (и тогда не указывать).

Comment: @perfect: ... или дописать правильно до `std::allocator<int>`.

А ещё лучше не выписывать типы вручную, а воспользоваться `auto` или в крайнем случае `decltype`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зачем вы вообще указываете аллокатор для вектора, если не знаете что это такое? Уберите его и все заработает.

Answer (score -1):

Похоже на проблему необъявленного тэмлейта (т.е. Вы создаете экземпляр template класса iterator, видимо, не определив параметры template, а именно allocator, поэтому компилятор и не знает, что ему создавать), но трудно сказать, ничего не понимаю в этом тексте на русском.

`std::vector<int>::iterator it;` - так должно получиться. У Вас allocator где-то объявлен?

Comment: нет не объявлен, думал в заголовках под тип vector<int> есть. итератор создаю для очистки вектора от дубликатов. просто так он не очищаетца. вот немного кода:

    typedef std::vector<int> IntVector;
    std::vector<IntVector> theGeneralVector;
    .............
    std::sort(theGeneralVector[i].begin(), theGeneralVector[i].end());
    theGeneralVector[i].erase(std::unique(theGeneralVector[i].begin(), theGeneralVector[i].end()), theGeneralVector[i].end());

Comment: Надо объявить.)) Иначе std::vector<int, allocator>::iterator не тип.